# Question about solving string of inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose I have a string of inequalities, i.e. 
$$
f(x,y,z)<g(x,y,z)<h(x,y,z)
$$
Clearly, if I find when $g(x,y,z)<h(x,y,z)$ and $f<g$, then $f<h$ when both these conditions hold.

> Is it ever useful to compare $f(x,y,z)<h(x,y,z)$ *in addition* to $f<g$ and $g<h$?
>
> Or is it useful to compare the conditions (assuming I can get them in a comparable form) from $g<h$ and $f<h$ to each other? Maybe comparing the two can give a single, simplified condition for $f<g<h$ to hold?

More generally, I get confused when I have systems of many $\geq 3$ inequalities about when i can substitute the results from comparing two of the inequalities into another inequality (or the results from comparing 2 other inequalities)

Comment: To solve the gven inequality we need to solve $f<g$ and $g<h$. We don not need to check for $f<h$.

Comment: Well, if you get $f \ge h$ then the statement is false.  So what's more important doing the least amount of work to show something is false or doing the least amount of work to show something is false.

Comment: if 1 < 2 and 2 < 3, its obvious than 1 hastobe< 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$f(x,y,z)<g(x,y,z)<h(x,y,z)$$

is equivalent to the following system

- $f(x,y,z)<g(x,y,z)$
- $g(x,y,z)<h(x,y,z)$

and the condition $f(x,y,z)<h(x,y,z)$ is implicitely assumed by the system.